# How to make SNS Topic to reject specific events?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have a lambda which handles SNS Events.

I would like to block specific events in SNS. For example, if event contains specific ID, I want SNS topic to reject it. Basically, I do not want that message to be in topic/queue.

I checked the AWS documentation which only allows [filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/message-filtering-apply.html). However, instead of allowing specific attributes(for my case it is ID) to pass, I would like to block specific events to be in SNS topic/queue.

Do you have any idea to do it ?

Comment: An SNS message ID is uniquely generated when an SNS message is published. At that point in time, SNS immediately publishes the message to subscribers. Are you trying to filter on message ID (if so, how would the ID be meaningful at that point?) or some other ID?

Comment: What I mean by ID is not event ID but a kind of attribute in data. For example, services send data which contains Football Club Name. I would like my SNS topic to reject if football club name is Barcelona but allow anything except Barcelona.

Comment: OK, thanks for confirming. You might also look into EventBridge as the target for these messages rather than SNS because EventBridge supports content-based filtering.

Comment: It is an existing system which uses SNS but I did not know the EventBridge, I will check it too. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't such a functionality in SNS service itself. The filtering is for different use-case and not for selective selection of notifications. I suggest a lambda function fronting whichever service is triggering the notification. Lambda function should have all the logic of clearing the non-required IDs.

Current:

> Some service -> SNS Topic -> Lambda

Suggested implementation:

> Some Service -> New Lambda (Logic here) -> SNS Topic -> Lambda